# Adding search box for admin on custom admin page

Tags: search, admin-menu

I have fetched some rows on my custom admin page (using hook for adding admin menus).
Now I want to add a search box on that page to display only those rows with the 'title' column containing searched string in that column.

I'm trying with

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE %
```

to get the data. Please give me some idea.
How to do this stuff?

Comment: I really have no idea what you are doing. Please try to explain the problem better.

Comment: Sorry for this bad description. Actually I was trying to fetch rows by comparing the strings in the rows with column name as title. Now I've got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fetched some rows on my custom admin page (using hook for adding admin menus).
I wanted to add a search box on that page to display only those rows with the 'name' column containing searched string in that column.

```
ID     |    Name
_________________
1      |    abc
2      |    abc
3      |    abz
4      |    xyz
_________________
```

I was trying with

```
$keyword = $_POST['data'];
$poi_sql="SELECT * FROM Details WHERE Name LIKE %".$keyword;
```

I got this::

```
$keyword = $_POST['data'];
$poi_sql="SELECT Name FROM Details WHERE Name LIKE '%". $keyword ."%'";
```

Silly mistakes. P)

Comment: Please tell that is not your final production code. That is a SQL injection playground.

Comment: @s_ha_dum yeah, that's right.

Comment: What is right? "not your final code" or "SQL injection playground"?

Comment: Its not the final code

Comment: It is preferable to note known issues with the code, especially security issues. There is a recent question in meta: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/2472/21376